# Prestashop 1.7.x differences cookies

Tags: session, cookies, prestashop

I am using cookies successfully in Prestashop but I am not clear what is the difference between this way

```
$context = Context::getContext();
$context->cookie->__set("mycookie","myvalue");
```

and this

```
$cookie = new Cookie('mycookie');
$cookie->setExpire(time() + 30 * 60); 
$cookie->variable_name = ......
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Context` in prestashop is you can say global object; which keeps detailed information of main objects that is used mainly regularly; for ex. cart, customer, link etc. Context keeps details of below objects;

```
/** @var Cart */
public $cart;

/** @var Customer */
public $customer;

/** @var Cookie */
public $cookie;

/** @var Link */
public $link;

/** @var Country */
public $country;

/** @var Employee */
public $employee;

/** @var AdminController|FrontController */
public $controller;

/** @var string */
public $override_controller_name_for_translations;

/** @var Language */
public $language;

/** @var Currency */
public $currency;

/** @var AdminTab */
public $tab;

/** @var Shop */
public $shop;

/** @var Theme */
public $theme;

/** @var Smarty */
public $smarty;
```

So in context as you can see `Cookie` object is also included.

When you use `new Cookie('mycookie');` it will use separate Cookie class to create object.